# how to set array elements equal to the number of chars in a word

Tags: java

Create and assign, to instance variable progress, a new array of char with a number of elements equal to the length of the String you just assigned to word. (I have a set of words that gets assigned to string "word")

I honestly dont know a simple way to do this. I can think of some long ways but it seems from context that there is a simple way.

Comment: Could it be as simple as `progress = new char[word.length()]`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code,

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String testString = sc.nextLine();
    char[] stringToCharArray = testString.toCharArray();

    for (char output : stringToCharArray) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
    sc.close();
```

Output:

```
word
w
o
r
d
```